Is there a way to upload a file with metadata in a single request with SDK v12?
With Azure blob storage sdk v12, is there a way to create a blob reference locally, add metadata to it and upload file content and metadata to blob storage in one go?
We could do that before with CloudBlockBlob.Metadata.Add but i cannot find corresponding mechanism in v12.
Is that possible?

Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written for uploading. It is certainly possible to do so.

@GauravMantri I havent written any code sice I haven't found any way to do it when looking into documentation ans migration documentation.

Please take a look at BlockBlobClient.Upload(Stream, BlobUploadOptions, CancellationToken) method. You would specify Metadata in BlobUploadOptions.
Here's the sample code to do so:
        public async Task EditBlobWithMetadata()
        {
            string data = "hello world";
            var initialMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "fizz", "buzz" } };

            string containerName = Randomize("sample-container");
            var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(ConnectionString, containerName);

            try
            {
                containerClient.Create();
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(Randomize("sample-blob"));
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(BinaryData.FromString(data), new BlobUploadOptions { Metadata = initialMetadata });

                #region Snippet:SampleSnippetsBlobMigration_EditBlobWithMetadata
                // download blob content and metadata
                BlobDownloadResult blobData = blobClient.DownloadContent();

                // modify blob content
                string modifiedBlobContent = blobData.Content + "FizzBuzz";

                // reupload modified blob content while preserving metadata
                // not adding metadata is a metadata clear
                blobClient.Upload(
                    BinaryData.FromString(modifiedBlobContent),
                    new BlobUploadOptions() { Metadata = blobData.Details.Metadata });
                #endregion

                var actualMetadata = (await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync()).Value.Metadata;
                Assert.AreEqual(initialMetadata.Count, actualMetadata.Count);
                foreach (var expectedKvp in initialMetadata)
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(actualMetadata.TryGetValue(expectedKvp.Key, out var actualValue));
                    Assert.AreEqual(expectedKvp.Value, actualValue);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                await containerClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
            }
        }

Code reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/47ea075bca473fe6e9928ff9893fbaa8a552f3a5/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample03_Migrations.cs#L630

btw, is there a reason why it exists on that overload only?

I have no idea, sorry! You may want to ask this question on Azure SDK GitHub repo.
